# Remove public folder in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there any way to change the default folder structure of zend framework 2?
My specific need is to remove/rename public folder.
Also, I would like to remove public from URL also.
I tried many things using htaccess but nothing works for zend 2.

Answer (score 4):

The default folder structure is just a convention, there's nothing particular that relies on it. However, it is a sensible convention, and instead of trying to change it you should probably try and fix the real problem instead.

If `public/` is appearing in the URL, either your VirtualHost is not setup correctly or you're using shared hosting and can't change the VirtualHost. The [installation instructions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html#apache-setup) have example vhosts for Apache - the key thing is having your document root pointing at the public folder, not the application root.

Comment: thanks for the reply Tim. My plan is to put the website on a shared hosting, so what all precautions do I have to take for preventing unwanted attacks? also, how I can remove public from url on a shared host via htaccess?

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used ZF2 on shared hosting, so can't really help you there. There have been several other questions about this in the past though. If you are having trouble, it might be worth adding what you currently have in htaccess that isn't working to your question.